# Get a list of the elements under a certain table column

Tags: java, vaadin

This table is produced by my code below. (The table's data is rubbish)

[image]

**Question:**
How can I get a list of the items under a certain column in the order they appear?

I want to do something like table.GetListFromColumn("carmake") so I would have ["Aston Martin" , "Porche 911", "ferrari"].

Or beanItemContainer.GetListFromColumn("carmake")?

```
@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    BrakeResponseTime time1 = new BrakeResponseTime(0.2f);
    BrakeResponseTime time2 = new BrakeResponseTime(0.8f);
    BrakeResponseTime time3 = new BrakeResponseTime(0.5f);

    Collection<SportsCar>c = new ArrayList<SportsCar>();
    c.add(new SportsCar("ferrari", 180.0, "Tom", time1));
    c.add(new SportsCar("Aston Martin", 165.0, "Harry", time2));
    c.add(new SportsCar("Porche 911", 145.0, "Dick", time3));

    MyBeanItemContainer container = new MyBeanItemContainer(SportsCar.class,c);

    Table table = new Table();
    t.setContainerDataSource(container);
    this.setContent(table);

}
```

.

```
public class BrakeResponseTime implements Comparable<BrakeResponseTime> {

float time;

/**
 * Create a Demo.BrakeResponseTime.
 */
public BrakeResponseTime(float time) {
    this.time = time;
}

/**
 * Get the time.
 * 
 * @return the time.
 */
public float getTime() {
    return time;
}

/**
 * Set the time.
 * 
 * @param time
 *            the time.
 */
public void setTime(float time) {
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return time +"/%";
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(BrakeResponseTime o) {
    if (null == o) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(time==o.getTime()){
        return 0;
    }
    return (time < o.getTime() ? -1 : 1);
}

}
```

.

```
public class MyBeanItemContainer extends BeanItemContainer<SportsCar> {
/**
 * Create a Demo.MyBeanItemContainer.
 */
public MyBeanItemContainer(Class<SportsCar> type, Collection<SportsCar> collection) {
    super(type, collection);
}

private int compareBrakeResponseTimeWithNullCheck(BrakeResponseTime o1, BrakeResponseTime o2) {
    if (null == o1 && (null == o2)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (null == o1 && (null != o2)) {
        return -1;
    }else if(null != o1 && (null == o2)){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}

@Override
public void sort(final Object[] propertyId, final boolean[] ascending) {
    super.sort(propertyId, ascending);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(propertyId));
    final boolean sortAscending = ascending[0];
    final Object sortContainerPropertyId = propertyId[0];
    List<SportsCar> list = super.getAllItemIds();
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SportsCar>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final SportsCar o1, final SportsCar o2) {
            int result = 0;
            if ("responseTime".equals(sortContainerPropertyId)) {
                result = compareBrakeResponseTimeWithNullCheck(o1.getResponseTime(), o2.getResponseTime());
            }

            if (!sortAscending) {
                result *= -1;
            }
            return result;
        }
    });
}
}



public class SportsCar {
String carMake;
double topspeed;
String driver;
BrakeResponseTime responseTime;

public SportsCar(String carMake, double topspeed, String driver, BrakeResponseTime responseTime) {

    this.carMake = carMake;
    this.topspeed = topspeed;
    this.driver = driver;
    this.responseTime = responseTime;
}

/**
 * Get the carMake.
 * 
 * @return the carMake.
 */
public String getcarMake() {
    return carMake;
}

/**
 * Set the carMake.
 * 
 * @param carMake
 *            the carMake.
 */
public void setcarMake(String carMake) {
    this.carMake = carMake;
}

/**
 * Get the topspeed.
 * 
 * @return the topspeed.
 */
public double getTopspeed() {
    return topspeed;
}

/**
 * Set the topspeed.
 * 
 * @param topspeed
 *            the topspeed.
 */
public void setTopspeed(double topspeed) {
    this.topspeed = topspeed;
}

/**
 * Get the driver.
 * 
 * @return the driver.
 */
public String getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

/**
 * Set the driver.
 * 
 * @param driver
 *            the driver.
 */
public void setDriver(String driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

/**
 * Get the responseTime.
 * @return the responseTime.
 */
public BrakeResponseTime getResponseTime() {
    return responseTime;
}

/**
 * Set the responseTime.
 * @param responseTime the responseTime.
 */
public void setResponseTime(BrakeResponseTime responseTime) {
    this.responseTime = responseTime;
}


}
```

Comment: is this about getting formatted/filtered values?  or why can't you just use your container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't realised I could access the bean container's properties in this way.

```
container.getIdByIndex(0).getCarMake()
```

This is what I was looking for!